# Sorting and Display Search Results Without Display them First

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, sorting, search

I have the [Tables Sort Script](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list) which sort results.

However, i want the script to sort and display results **AFTER** the search.

I mean, instead of this display:
[image]

It will show only the search input (without results):

[image]

So only **AFTER** i enter some text in the input, **THEN** i will got the immidiat results:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      #myInput {
        background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
        background-position: 10px 12px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
      }

      #myUL {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      #myUL li a {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: black;
        display: block;
      }

      #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
        background-color: #eee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

    <input
      type="text"
      id="myInput"
      onkeyup="myFunction()"
      placeholder="Search for names.."
      title="Type in a name"
    />

    <ul id="myUL"></ul>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var items = ['Adele', 'Agnes', 'Billy', 'Bob', 'Calvin', 'Christina', 'Cindy'];
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById('myInput');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

        ul = document.getElementById('myUL');
        ul.innerHTML = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          const item = items[i];
          if (filter && item.toUpperCase().includes(filter.toUpperCase())) {
            ul.innerHTML += `<li><a href="#">${item}</a></li>`;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```